# How to delete files created with ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL in c++?

Tags: c++, ios, audiotoolbox

I am doing low level audio processing on iOS. As a result parts of my application are written in c++.

There I create and write to audio files. Files are created using *ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL* and written to using *ExtAudioFileWriteAsync*. Files are closed using *ExtAudioFileDispose*.

Sometimes files need to be deleted.

How do I delete files created with *ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL* in c++?

Since the files are opened with a *CFURLRef* the function *CFURLDestroyResource* seems to be the way to do this, but this function is deprecated and it is unclear to me what would replace this function.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to tackle this problem by writing a helper function in a Objective-C file and calling that function from the C++ code.

```
bool removeItemAtURL(CFURLRef url) {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    return [fileManager removeItemAtURL: (__bridge NSURL *)url error: NULL];
}
```

Although this works I am unsure if it is save to use the NSFilemanger object in a time critical audio rendering thread. If so then it would be best to let deletion of files be handled in a different thread.